# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' for submodule, have imported Common, Forms and Reactive

Tags: angular

I know this has been asked all over, but hey, mines a little different. I am converting to lazy loading and I have imported the common, forms and reactive modules into my submodules module and still get the error. If I move the component back into the main module, all is back to working.

Here's my sub-module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerComponent } from './customerApp.CustomerComponent';
import{ MainRoutes } from '../Routing/customerApp.MainRouting';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(MainRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [CustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

I move the component back to the main module and all is working:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerComponent } from '../Customer/customerApp.CustomerComponent';
import { HomeComponent } from './customerApp.HomeComponent';
import { MasterPageComponent } from './customerApp.MasterPageComponent';
import{ MainRoutes } from '../Routing/customerApp.MainRouting'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    MasterPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(MainRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MasterPageComponent]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

This is a brand new project created with Angular 9.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please indicate what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out, that I needed to finish my routing setup for it to work... i.e.: once I set:

```
import { HomeComponent } from "../Home/customerApp.HomeComponent"

    export const MainRoutes = [
        {path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent},
        { path: 'Customer', loadChildren: () => import('src/customerApp/Customer/customerApp.CustomerModule').then(m => m.CustomerModule) },
        { path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: () => import('src/customerApp/Supplier/customerApp.SupplierModule').then(m => m.SupplierModule) }
    ]
```

for the customer module, it compiled successfully AHHHHHHHHH!